# Choice field initial data

Tags: django

I have form like below. How can I get a value selected?

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):

name = forms.CharField(label=_('Full Name'))
about = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), label=_('Tell something about you'))
country = forms.CharField(label=_('Country'), required=False)

def __init__(self, tz_choice=0, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    country_list = Country.objects.all().order_by('name')

    country_opt = [('', _('Select'))]
    for ct in country_list:
        country_opt.append([ct.country_code, ct.name])

    self.fields['country'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=country_opt, initial='NP')
```

In above example, I want Nepal to be selected.

Comment: That's exactly how you do it. `initial`. Is a country with value `NP` in there? I just tested this and it works... `MyChoiceField.initial = 'whatever'`

Comment: Yep the country NP is in choice list. I tried with couple of country but doesn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using ModelChoiceField

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):

   name = forms.CharField(label=_('Full Name'))
   about = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), label=_('Tell something about you'))
   country = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=_('Country'), queryset=Country.objects.all(), required=False,initial=Country.objects.get(code="np").pk)
```

Comment: How to render this to the template i.e this the initial value in the option tag must be show selected